# Loading URL With Basic HTTP Authentication In Swift

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to send NSURLConnection.SendAsynchronousRequest to a URL that requests an authentication.
I'm implementing the method:

```
func connection(connection:NSURLConnection!, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge:NSURLAuthenticationChallenge!) {

    if challenge.previousFailureCount > 1 {

    } else {
        println("Asking for auth")
        let creds = NSURLCredential(user: usernameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text, persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.None)
        challenge.sender.useCredential(creds, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
```

The method is not being called, also the line is not being printed.

Am i doing everything right?
I'm new to coding with swift, it seems right to me but it just doesn't work...

Comment: You may find more Swift examples for the newer NSURLSession classes.

Comment: Good news/bad news.  Good news!  You are not alone.  I'm porting an app from where I use willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge and it works fine in obj-c.  It's not being called in Swift.  The method is in NSURLConnectionDelegate and the signature looks good for it.  I'll take another pass at it later today.

Answer (score 0):

(new edit) Hmm.  rebooted and now it is calling willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge is being called.  I didn't change any of the code, so Xcode must have gotten in an odd state.  If I figure out more, I'll update.

(original post)
Seems to be a problem in Xcode 6 Beta 4.  I put my code back in Beta 3 and my willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge is being called.  I'll run for this as a temp workaround for now.

I did file a radar with Apple on this one.